# excel-vba Run-time error '1004'

Tags: vba, excel

***Below is my code***

```
Range("M2").Select
Selection.FormulaArray = _
    "=IF(AND(RC8<=R1C,RC9>=EOMONTH(R1C,0)),INDEX(Planned!R2C:R100C,MATCH(1,(RC3=Planned!R2C3:R100C3)*(RC10=Planned!R2C10:R100C10)*(RC12=Planned!R2C12:R100C12),0)),ROUND((MAX(R1C[1]-MAX(RC8,R1C),0)-MAX(R1C[1]-MAX(RC9,R1C),0))*INDEX(Planned!R2C:R100C,MATCH(1,(RC3=Planned!R2C3:R100C3)*(RC10=Planned!R2C10:R100C10)*(RC12=Planned!R2C12:R100C12),0))/DAY(EOMONTH(R1C,0)),0))"
```

***When I try to run macro it's giving me below error***

[image]

***Any thoughts on this?***

Comment: Keep in mind that `Range.FormulaArray` is limited to 255 chars.

Comment: ohh..is their any way to apply this formula using macro.

Comment: As said by @pk_22 you could do a `Range("M2").FormulaArray = "=IF(""XXX"",""YYY"",""ZZZ"")"`. Then use `Range.Replace`-method for the 3 parts of the `IF`-function. Keep in mind that each replacement itself has the same 255-char-restriction.

Comment: Please try my suggestion with send keys, ( I post my answer) it works and it is easy to understand how it works...you simulate the way you make the formula array...

Comment: @Dirk..when i try to replace      `Range("M2").Replace What:="XXX", Replacement:="AND(RC8<=R1C,RC9>=EOMONTH(R1C,0))", MatchCase:=True` this gives me below output `=IF("AND(RC8<=R1C,RC9>=EOMONTH(R1C,0))","YYY","ZZZ")` output should contain cell references but its replacing as a text..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you save parts of the formula in variables? And then call the variables in the Formula array? To save on characters? So simply split the equation.

So for example:

```
var1 = DAY(EOMONTH(R1C,0))
```

and then replace it in your formula. Do this for several parts which are easy to replace by a variable.

Comment: `Range("M2").FormulaArray = "=IF(""XXX"",""YYY"",""ZZZ"")"
Range("M2").Replace What:="XXX", Replacement:="AND($H2<=M$1,$I2>=EOMONTH(M$1,0))", MatchCase:=True
Range("M2").Replace What:="YYY", Replacement:="INDEX(Planned!M$2:M$100,MATCH(1,($C2=Planned!$C$2:$C$100)*($J2=Planned!$J$2:$J$100)*($L2=Planned!$L$2:$L$100),0))", MatchCase:=True
Range("M2").Replace What:="ZZZ", Replacement:="ROUND((MAX(N$1-MAX($H2,M$1),0)-MAX(N$1-MAX($I2,M$1),0))*INDEX(Planned!M$2:M$100,MATCH(1,($C2=Planned!$C$2:$C$100)*($J2=Planned!$J$2:$J$100)*($L2=Planned!$L$2:$L$100),0))/DAY(EOMONTH(M$1,0)),0)", MatchCase:=True`

Comment: But I am getting " in output `=IF("AND($H2<=M$1,$I2>=EOMONTH(M$1,0))","INDEX(Planned!M$2:M$100,MATCH(1,($C2=Planned!$C$2:$C$100)*($J2=Planned!$J$2:$J$100)*($L2=Planned!$L$2:$L$100),0))","ROUND((MAX(N$1-MAX($H2,M$1),0)-MAX(N$1-MAX($I2,M$1),0))*INDEX(Planned!M$2:M$100,MATCH(1,($C2=Planned!$C$2:$C$100)*($J2=Planned!$J$2:$J$100)*($L2=Planned!$L$2:$L$100),0))/DAY(EOMONTH(M$1,0)),0)")`   Is there any way to remove this(")

Comment: I dont understand completely your question, but you are using double " around the XXX/YYY/ZZZ

Comment: ohh..yeahh its working without double "... thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what data you have in the various fields, does the following work?

```
ActiveSheet.Range("M2").Activate
With Selection
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
    "=IF(AND(RC8<=R1C,RC9>=EOMONTH(R1C,0)),INDEX(Planned!R2C:R100C,MATCH(1,
   (RC3=Planned!R2C3:R100C3)*(RC10=Planned!R2C10:R100C10)*
   (RC12=Planned!R2C12:R100C12),0)),ROUND((MAX(R1C[1]-MAX(RC8,R1C),0)-
   MAX(R1C[1]-MAX(RC9,R1C),0))*INDEX(Planned!R2C:R100C,MATCH(1,
   (RC3=Planned!R2C3:R100C3)*(RC10=Planned!R2C10:R100C10)*
   (RC12=Planned!R2C12:R100C12),0))/DAY(EOMONTH(R1C,0)),0))"
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

please change with this:
(The SendKeys method simulates keystrokes that you would manually input in the active window)

```
Range("M2").Select
Selection.Formula = _
    "=IF(AND(RC8<=R1C,RC9>=EOMONTH(R1C,0)),INDEX(Planned!R2C:R100C,MATCH(1,(RC3=Planned!R2C3:R100C3)*(RC10=Planned!R2C10:R100C10)*(RC12=Planned!R2C12:R100C12),0)),ROUND((MAX(R1C[1]-MAX(RC8,R1C),0)-MAX(R1C[1]-MAX(RC9,R1C),0))*INDEX(Planned!R2C:R100C,MATCH(1,(RC3=Planned!R2C3:R100C3)*(RC10=Planned!R2C10:R100C10)*(RC12=Planned!R2C12:R100C12),0))/DAY(EOMONTH(R1C,0)),0))"


 SendKeys "{F2}"
 SendKeys "^+{ENTER}"
```

Comment: No luck..its returning to #VALUE!

Comment: your formula length is over 255 characters, that's why you have this error

Comment: Please,be carefull don't write FormulaArray, write Formula

Comment: Yeah i am writing formula only..its not giving me same error..but its not able to convert in array formula..

Comment: sure..@Nikolaos

Comment: please don't run it from the VBE, try to run it from the sheets and it will work without problem

Comment: I kept your code in sheets and calling from VBE but still having same problem..:(

Comment: No, i don't mean that, run it from the front of the house, not from the code editor.
Run it from sheets environment.
Go to Developer-Macros-Your Macro -Run or Run it from a button or shortcut.

Comment: I am doing the same..if i keep only this code in VBE and run from sheets environment its working but when i am running same code in my project its not able to convert in array formula..:(

Comment: from where you run your project?

Comment: you can create a button or shortcut to run your project and then the above code will have no problem

Comment: The SendKeys method simulates keystrokes that you would manually input in the active window

Comment: I am pasting this code into my VBA project...i have created button to run the code, still not able to convert same in to array formula..

Comment: it is strange, please make sure that when your code reaches to the code we discuss, the range("M2") is activated.

Comment: please I you want send the code to test it, because this part(with the formulaArray) of the code it works perfectly (with the button click, shortcut or from: Developer-Macros-Your Macro -Run)

Comment: Thanks you..got another way to do this..thank you for support :)

Comment: Ok !! Have a nice day !